# How to pause a thread while a new one arrives, and resume when the new thread finishes

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, threadpool

I want to create a pooling system for threads that is different from the conventional pool. In this pool, whenever a new thread arrives, it has more priority, so for example there is thread 1 and then thread 2 arrives, thread 1 is paused until thread 2 finishes, and then resume after that. In this system I want that each thread has a reference to the new thread when it arrive.

This is my last try (forget the term dialogue I am making it for a dialogue system):

```
import threading
from queue import  PriorityQueue
import time


class DialogueThread():
        
    newest_thread = None

    @classmethod
    def set_newest_thread(cls, thread):
        cls.newest_thread = thread

    

    def get_value(self):
        return self.thread

    def __init__(self, task):
        self.task = task
        
        self.locker = threading.Event() # this event if for pausing and resuming the current thread
        self.locker.set()
        #TODO: how to access information of the new thread?
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.task, args=[self.locker])
        self.thread.start()

    

        w = threading.Thread(target=self.watch, args=[self.thread])
        w.start()
        
        DialogueThread.set_newest_thread(self.thread)
        
       
    def watch(self, thread: threading.Thread):
        
        while thread.is_alive():
                
                # if a new thread has arrived while this thread was working
                if self.thread != DialogueThread.newest_thread: 
                    #pause this thread
                    self.locker.clear()
                    
                #if the new thread is finished working
                if DialogueThread.newest_thread is not None and not  DialogueThread.newest_thread.is_alive():
                    #resume this thread
                    self.locker.set()


    



def thread1(locker : threading.Event):
     count = 0
     
     while count < 10:
        locker.wait()

        print(f"thread 1 is working: {count} ")
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
     print("thread1 is finished")


def thread2(locker : threading.Event):
     count = 0
     while count < 5:
        locker.wait()
        print(f"thread 2 is working: {count} ")
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)


         
     
thread_1 = DialogueThread(thread1)
time.sleep(5)
thread_2 = DialogueThread(thread2)
```

here I realized it is not possible to compare threads as they are mostly not the same, so that if statement in watch does not work.

Thank you!!

Comment: If you want thread 1 to pause while thread 2's code executes, and then when thread 2 is done, thread 1 resumes, it's much easier to obtain that behavior by simply getting rid of thread 2 and instead have thread 1 call (whatever function thread 2 was going to execute) directly instead.  Then you get that same behavior, but more efficiently and with a lot less complication.

Comment: So the problem is most of the time the second thread won't start while the first one is running, and the condition is not based on code but on user's input, so I should create this functionality in this specific way

Comment: In my experience you'd be better off sending a message/signal to the first thread, using one mechanism or another, to tell the first thread to call the subroutine you want to run.  The only reason to have multiple threads is to do multiple asynchronous operations *in parallel*, which is the opposite of what you seem to want to do here.